# regex to remove complete HTML entity

Tags: php, regex

We have a requirement to remove special characters from text strings. For example, we may get a string that looks like this; the `&#174;` is the registered trademark symbol:

`PEPSI&#174; Bottle 20 oz<br><br>`

I'm not great with regex, and can't figure out how to edit the existing code to produce that.

Here's what we currently have:

```
$ui = "PEPSI Bottle 20 oz<br><br>";
$ui = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\.\' -]/', '', $ui);
```

This results in `PEPSI174 Bottle 20 ozbrbr`.

Our desired result is `PEPSI Bottle 20 oz<br><br>`.

How can I edit the regex to make sure that

1. It doesn't remove valid HTML tags like `<br>`, and
2. If it does find a special character entity, it removes not only the special characters (the & and #), but also the numbers and semicolon?

We don't want to have it remove all the numbers, as obviously the string can contain numbers; it's only numbers that are part of the entity code that we need to remove.

Comment: There's a function for that? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: i am thinking about using ^ (start) and $ (end) to build something that says: start with <, ends with > and contains letters.

Comment: Also, there is one for decoding entities; http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: @SamSwift웃 She doesn't want to remove tags, she wants to remove entities.

Comment: The regular expression `&[^;]+;` matches all HTML entities.

Comment: @Barmar You should add `\s` to it otherwise it is prone to wrong matches. More better it should be more about word characters and not every non-whitespace one.

Comment: Personally I'd use something like this `/&#?\w+;/i`

Comment: @revo I assumed `&` would never appear except as the start of an entity, if you want a literal `&` you should write `&amp;`. But now I realize that this is often not the case, people write URLs in HTML without encoding the entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this but now I can't guaranty it covers all the possible HTML entities:

```
$res = preg_replace('/&[A-Za-z0-9#]+;/', '', $ui);
```

That says replace any substring that:
- starts with `&`
- followed by any number of alphanumeric characters or `#` in random order
- followed by `;`.

Comment: Technically, `#` can only be the first character after `#&`, but this is probably good enough.